# How to redirect a view if session exist? (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to make view can't be loaded if session is exist and redirect it to other view.
For example if user is logged in (session exist), the login page view should redirect to main page instead.
Currently my code is like this. This code can detect the session but redirect is not working (blank page).

```
<?php if (Session::has('sessionId')){return redirect('/front')} ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't return a redirect inside a view like that. It'll need to be in the controller (or better yet, use the `auth` middleware, which is specifically designed for this).

Comment: I remove the php code to route instead.
But next I'll try use Auth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this
organise import:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

your action in controller

```
public function actionName() //your action name from routes`{
if (Auth::check()) {
  return Redirect::to('/front'));
 }}`
```

Comment: Can you give more specific explanation? 
How to put that code and what should I write in it. Thanks.